# Java Gui get.Text(); not working

Tags: java

I got the code below to do a get text, but I have an issue. It gives me an error saying that it cannot be resolved. I'm new to `java gui`. Hope someone can help me. I tried using `nameP.getText();`, but didn't work. I'm not sure why it is a error?

```
 private class createListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Create Player");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
            JButton create;
            JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Create Player");
            JLabel name = new JLabel("Enter Player Name");
            JTextField nameP = new JTextField();
            JLabel pass = new JLabel("Enter Player Password");
            JTextField passwd = new JTextField();
            JLabel chips = new JLabel("Enter Player Chips");
            JTextField chipsP = new JTextField();
            buttonCreate = new JButton("Create Player");

            setSize(400,350);
            setLocation(500,280);
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,10,10));

            panel.add(name);
            panel.add(nameP);
            panel.add(pass);
            panel.add(passwd);
            panel.add(chips);
            panel.add(chipsP);
            panel.add(buttonCreate);
            mainpanel.add(panel);

            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(mainpanel);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            buttonCreate.addActionListener(new createListener());
        }

    }
    private class playerListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String name = nameP.getText();

    }
}
```

Comment: `nameP` is a local variable you're declaring in your `actionPerformed` method. How do you expect that to be available outside the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nameP` variable is `local` and thus you would not be able to reference it outside of the `actionPerformed`, outside of that scope `nameP` does not exist. You may declare it as a [class member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) variable if you wish to use it elsewhere.

```
JTextField nameP;

    private class createListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        nameP = new JTextField();
      }
    }

    private class playerListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String name = nameP.getText();
    }
```

Comment: "global" is a tricky word here. I think "class member" is more appropriate.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - You are correct, I'll edit that. Thanks for the suggestion